# Google drive api change ownership of files?

Tags: java, google-drive-api

I'm using the google drive api to manage some files of multiple users. 
Now I was wondering how I could transfer ownership for some Files to another user.

I was looking at the api documentation and noticed I needed a "permissionId". I don't know wich one I need. The current user or the user who gets it?)

I don't know what user has to be authenticated (with the drive service) the user who gets the files or the user who gives the files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will be only need to be authorized in as the user who owns the file, and you will grant the owner permission to the new owner, and grant it by email address. Then you can remove the owner permission for the authorized (previous owner) user. You can remove this using the permission ID, which is in the about feed for the user.

Remember that ownership can only stay within the domain.

Comment: I keep getting error 500(internal server error) if I try to set a new owner. When I try writer or reader it always works.

Comment: I found out why. I was trying to give ownership to a user outside the domain.

Comment: I have tried this and change the ownership to another user (2), then the file is found in both user (1) and user (2) in the "shared files" path.

But then the permission is removed from user (1) that was the first owner of a file, the file disappear from user (2) as well. The only way to find the file for user (2) is to search for the right filename. Is this a bug?

Comment: This approach of transferring ownership works for doc files and fails for txt files. Both doc and txt files are uploaded to source drive using google web ui. Is something special needed to handle all mimeTypes?