# Transfer file ownership with google drive API

Tags: google-drive-api

I am trying to create a Java application to manage user accounts on Google Apps. One of the requirements is to transfer all the files owned by a user before I delete that user.

I am using Google Drive API to insert a file permission on the file being transferred:

POST https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/{fileId}/permissions
{
  "role":"owner"
  "type":"user"
  "value":"transferuser@domain.com"
}

I received the HTTP 500 "Internal Error".

I am using the OAuth 2.0 to authenticate to Google Apps and my service account impersonates an admin user with all the administrative roles available on Google Apps.

It seems that the only thing I could not do is to change the file ownership of the files that are not owned by the admin user.

Anyone has an idea how to get this work.

Thanks
JP

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google drive api change ownership of files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12249232/google-drive-api-change-ownership-of-files)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [transfer file ownership in Google Drive API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42788967/transfer-file-ownership-in-google-drive-api)